# Why my helper doesn't re-run when the collection I call inside it is updated?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper, minimongo

I have a template with a video player. It gets the video source from a mongo document, using an helper. Here is how it looks like:

The helper:

```
'currentItemUrl' : function() {
    //I only have one project. Is there a better/cleaner way to obtain it than the one below?
    var currentProject = Projects.find().fetch()[0]; 
    //the function below will create an instance of videojs or update the current one (set the new source)
    loadPlayer();
    //I return the source url if I have one
    return currentProject.setup.player.item_loaded.url?currentProject.setup.player.item_loaded.url:"";
}
```

And the HTML looks like that:

```
<video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
    width = "{{videoWidth}}" height="videoHeight"
    poster="{{currentItemPoster}}">
    <source id="mp4" src="{{currentItemUrl}}" type='video/mp4' />
    <source id="webm" src="" type='video/webm' />
    <source id="ogg" src="" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

**The question**

How can I make sure that my helper is re-run when I update my `Projects` collection in another template? Since I use a `Collection.find()` shouldn't it already be reactive?

Comment: You should not put any side-effects inside your template helpers code. They should only read values. Instead, consider using `onRendered` callback and call `loadPlayer()` over there.

Comment: There is a tricky part I didn't mention in the question. I wanted my player to be agnostic of the video source. In order to set its size correctly (whatever the source size/ratio is), I load my source once in the form `rendered` function, and then I hook on the  `loadedmetadata` in order to load videojs first with the right ratio and size. I will probably wrap the whole thing (before the `loadedmetadata` event)  into a `template.autorun()` within the `rendered` function and get rid of the helper. Thank you for the comment @apendua.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your first question (in the comments of your code), if you only have one document at any point in time then there is a much simpler way with [`findOne`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone):

```
var currentProject = Projects.findOne();
```

Instead of a heavy ternary for your defaulting you could simply use the [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) :

```
//Always place the default on the right, since '' is falsey
return (currentProject.setup.player.item_loaded.url || '');
```

And because you use `find` (or `findOne` which is basically the same thing except it returns one document) it will always be reactive. If the document changes, then Tracker computations will invalidate and your helper [uses such a computation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) :

> Under the hood, each helper starts a new Tracker.autorun. When its reactive dependencies change, the helper is rerun. Helpers depend on their data context, passed arguments and other reactive data sources accessed during execution.

However, as [apendua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817257/apendua) noted in a comment, your helper triggers side-effects (`loadPlayer()`) - This is generally considered a bad practice because a helper is very similar to a getter: You just expect it to *return* data, not *alter* anything. You may want to run another [Tracker computation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) for this job.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much this is clear and meaningful. It works like a charm when I wrap my helper content inside a `this.autorun()` within my `rendered` function.

Comment: I assume that the ternary is "heavy" in terms of code readability but, just to check:  does it has lower performances? Besides its poor readability, is there any other reason it should be disregarded in favor of another approach in a case of if/then/else computation? (i.e. not exactly the one I used in this case, where I agree that `||` is much simpler).

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Meh, there's no big use in knowing which has more performance. I mean, if you overall manage to save 10ms of computation for each thousand times this is ran, why would you care? Why would your users? It's the kind of micro-optimisations you only do server-side for extremely specific purposes... Your biggest bottleneck is generally the network for the Web, not the CPU.

Comment: As I am still new to Javascript, I wondered if there is a better practice in that case. Not that I am especially focused on performance (or micro-optimization in that matter). I guess my answer in yours anyway. Thanks :-)